# Echo, "was unexpected" during redirection

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I am currently creating a math game and it will record the correct and incorrect answers to a text file (report.txt.)

The problem is when I am redirecting text to a file (report.txt)

Here is a part of my script that have the error:

```
set count=1
set line=5 + 2 x 8 x 6
set ans=7
set lev=1
(echo %count%.(%line%=%ans%) correct +%lev%) >> report.txt
pause
```

Comment: Put spaces around it. And remove the brackets or escape them with `^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(echo %count%.(%line%=%ans%^) correct +%lev%) >> report.txt
```

Since you want to produce the *literal* `)`, you need to "escape" the `)` with `^` so that it's interpreted as a literal, not the end of the statement `(echo ...`

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses within parentheses are bad syntax, you can either do this:

```
(echo %count%.^(%line%=%ans%^) correct +%lev%) >> report.txt
```

This will work too, but isn't all that stable.

```
echo %count%.(%line%=%ans%) correct +%lev% >> report.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't all that stable"? the only difference I see is the trailing space appended to the output...

Comment: @aschipfl the parentheses aren't in a code block, and in this situation they don't need to be escaped, but unescaped parentheses just creep me out.